# How to compare two maps with keys having multiple values?

Tags: java, collections

I have following two maps in the following manner:

```
Map<String,List<String>> sourceTags = sourceList.get(block);
Map<String,List<String>> targetTags = targetList.get(block);
```

I want to compare the list of values in sourceTags with list of values in targetTags corresponding to the key.

Now, the values in a map entry will be in the following manner :

```
SourceTag = [20C=[:ABC//0000000519983150], 22F=[:CAMV//MAND, :CAMV//MANDA], 98A[:XDTE//20160718,:MEET//20160602,:RDTE//20160719]
TargetTag = [20C=[:ABC//0000000519983150], 22F=[:CAMV//MAND],98A=[:MEET//20160602,:RDTE//20160719]
```

I want the output as below :

> Blockquote

key-22F, compare the list of values with sub-key being CAMV, if sub-key exists, the compare the difference, else if sub-key not exists then also report.

> Blockquote

Again, Key-98A, sub-Keys:XDTE,MEET,RDTE. If sub-key exists and found difference in values in source and target, then report. else if sub-key not found report as not found in source or target, same is the case with values.

```
if(sub-key found){
//compare their values
}else{
//report as sub-key not found
}
```

I have written the following program :

---

**EDITED the Program**

Set tags = sourceTags.keySet();

```
        for(String targetTag : tags){

            if(targetTags.containsKey(targetTag)){

                List<String> sourceValue = sourceTags.get(targetTag);
                List<String> targetValue = targetTags.get(targetTag);


                for(String sValue : sourceValue){

                    for(String tValue : targetValue){

                        if(sValue.length() > 4 && tValue.length() > 4){
                            //get keys for both source and target
                            String sKey = sValue.substring(1, 5);
                            String tKey = tValue.substring(1,5);

                            //get values for both source and target
                            String sTagValue= sValue.substring(sValue.lastIndexOf(sKey), sValue.length());
                            String tTagValue = tValue.substring(tValue.lastIndexOf(tKey),tValue.length());

                            if(sKey.equals(tKey)){
                                if(!sTagValue.equals(tTagValue)){
                                    values = createMessageRow(corpValue, block ,targetTag, sTagValue,tTagValue);
                                    result.add(values);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println(sourceTags.get(targetTag).get(0));
                values = createMessageRow(corpValue,block,targetTag,sourceTags.get(targetTag).get(0),"","Tag: "+targetTag+" not availlable in target");
                result.add(values);
            }
```

After executing, the comparison report shows wrong values.

Please help!!

Comment: This is a great candidate for test driven development.  It will force you to break your conditionals out into their own functions, answer the question you are currently asking, and save the sanity of the next developer that needs to modify this code.

Comment: Yes, breaking up your code is key here. Probably you never heard about the "single layer of abstraction" principle. Study it ... your code could benefit dramatically from that.

Comment: I provided the complete program, so that no one says that i have not done anything for this problem. Now, just writing the logic what i have done so far on this or Should I remove the above code ?

Comment: Cant you try to refactor the code into a smaller blocks so it's more readable? Name the methods meaningfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your code has a major logical flow. When you compare the List contained in the two Maps accessed with the same key, you do this:

```
for(int index = 0; index < Math.max(sourceValue.size(), targetValue.size()); index ++ ){
    if(index<sourceValue.size() && index<targetValue.size()){
         //Do your comparations...   
    }
```

That means that you proceed along the two lists with the same index and then you compare the two items. You never compare an item of the first list with an item of the second list that doesn't have the same index.

I'll give you an example: having two lists

```
LIST_A = (A, B, C)  
LIST_B = (C, B, A)
```

these are the comparisons you're making:

```
A == C
B == B
C == A
```

It's obvious then that even if the two lists contains the same elements the only correspondence you'll find is B == B.

You need to compare every item of the first list with ALL the items of the second one, to get all the matching pairs. Something like (without optimizations and elegance for clarity's sake):

```
    for(String sValue : sourceValue){
        for(String tValue : targetValue){
            if(sValue.length() > 4 && tValue.length() > 4){
                String sKey = sValue.substring(1,5);
                String tKey = tValue.substring(1,5);
                if(sKey.equals(tKey)){
                    //Do your logic...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This way, you don't even need to proceed in the other list when the index reaches the end of the first one like you do now...

Comment: Thanks Matt, i made the same changes in the program, it does the same work. Just one thing needs to added, else condition

Comment: I mean to say if the sub-key is not available in second list, Then also we have to report as the sub-key not available.